# How to connect Data Lake store in Azure analysis services

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

How to connect Data Lake store in Azure analysis services

Can we use HIVE ODBC or any other options?

Comment: *Microsoft Azure Data Lake Store supports any application that uses the open Apache Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) standard*. Are you running Hive in HDInsights? You can use any Hadoop HDFS client library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use Azure Data Lake as a data source for Azure Analysis Services (e.g. you have fact and dimension files in the Data Lake).

There is no connector in Azure Analysis Services to pull data directly from Azure Data Lake at present, although hopefully this is something Microsoft will address soon.

As a workaround you could try the following:

Azure Analysis Services will allow you to use Azure Blob Storage as a data source.  So once you have transformed your data in Azure Data Lake you then need to copy the fact and dimension files into Azure Blob Storage (e.g. using Azure Data Factory) and then you should be able to use Azure Analysis Services to build your model.

Note that the Blob Storage data source option is only available if you build a 1400 compatibility model in Azure Analysis Services.  This option is only available if you have the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio (you may need to upgrade to version 17.1 of SSDT).

I hope this helps

Comment: now this is solve please see this link-https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/09/05/using-azure-analysis-services-on-top-of-azure-data-lake-storage/

Comment: @user3843858 please, post this comment as separate answer and accept it, as this really answers the question and will be helpful for future visitors